# Two people on single ticket in Venice

Tags: tickets, public-transport, venice

is it possible to validate a ticket for a vaporetto twice, ie. to allow travelling for two people on single ticket? Or every passenger has to have his own ticket? I have 4 rides left on mine and my friend has none so it would be great if we can use that instead of buying new ticket. I didnt find anything on ACTV website... Thanks!

Comment: What kind of ticket do you have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I got official response from ACTV.

> We reply to your request informing that If the  travel card includes more than one tickets ( ie. 4 waterbus rides)  you can validate them for the other passengers.
>
> For instruction please visit this link:
>
> http://actv.avmspa.it/en/content/validating-actv-travel-documents-simple-0
>
> Thank you for writing us, kindest regards
>
> Back office call center Hellovenezia
>
> Servizio Vendite indirette e Customer service
>
> www.velaspa.com                      www.veneziaunica.it
>
> VE.LA. S.p.A.
>
> Isola Nova del Tronchetto, 21 - 30135 Venezia
>
> T. +39 041 2424
>
> F. +39 041 2722693

I'll quote the part containing info from the mentioned website:

> Do you have tickets on your card that you want to validate for your travel companions to use?
>
> 1)    After you have validated for yourself, move your card away from the validator;
>
> 2)    press [ ? ] and wait for the yellow light;
>
> 3)    near your card to the centre of the validator within 3 seconds (see picture);
>
> 4)    keep it there, read the ticket titles on the display and press [ OK ]  when the ticket you want appears: you have validated another ticket! Then, press   [ + ] the same numbers of times as the number of extra tickets you need. Press [ - ]   if you have to subtract tickets. Finally press [ OK ]

What is even funnier is that I asked the same question in the ticket booth and I was told, that **it isn't possible and every traveller has to carry his own ticket**.

So probably you can either stick to the email response I got and possibly face italian ticket controller (there may be a language barrier) or play it safe and buy separate tickets.

If anyone has anything to add, feel free to comment or post, I'll incorporate the info in this answer.